# Disable of sharing values

Tags: haskell

I am reading Haskell book and trying to understand what `IO` does.

Consider the following example:

```
import Debug.Trace
blah :: IO String
blah = return "blah"
blah' = trace "outer trace" blah

woot :: IO String
woot = return (trace "inner trace" "woot")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  b <- blah'
  putStrLn b
  putStrLn b
  w <- woot
  putStrLn w
  putStrLn w
```

The output in *GHCi:*

```
Prelude> main
outer trace
blah
blah
inner trace
woot
woot
```

Then the author says:

> We only saw inner and outer emitted once because IO is not
>   intended to disable sharing for values not in IO that happen to be
>   used in the course of running of an IO action.

What is the author trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That quote does seem hard to parse, but here's what I *think* it means:

When you use `<-` to refer to the value inside of `IO`, `b` and `w` become `String` values. `String` values are pure (referentially transparent), so can be shared.

The ability to share values is a benefit of pure functions and value. While you can't call an impure function from a pure function, you can call a pure function from an impure context, but we don't want the impure context to change the properties of the part of our code that's referentially transparent.

Haskell is lazily evaluated, so you *could* think that when you call `putStrLn b` twice, it'd lazily evaluate `blah'` twice, but it doesn't, because `b` is bound to the evaluated result of calling `putStrLn b`, not to `putStrLn b` itself.

In other words, you can share referentially transparent values between several function calls, and `IO` doesn't disable that property.

Comment: The last sentence, that you've mentioned `share referentially transparent values between several function calls` could you please show an example?

Comment: @zero_coding You have two examples of that in the OP code: `b` is shared between two calls to `putStrLn`, as is `w`.

Comment: These two are `referentially transparent values`.

Comment: @zero_coding Yes(?)